# Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize second HDD

Tags: 16.04

I installed a HDD as second drive. I want to use it as a backup.
But or one or the other reason Ubuntu doesn't want to recognize it although I did all the instructions I could find on the forum.

Pls some more advice.

```
root@jan-desktop:~# lsblk 

NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda 8:0 0 256.2G 0 disk 
├─sda1 8:1 0 46.4G 0 part 
├─sda2 8:2 0 1K 0 part 
├─sda5 8:5 0 7.6G 0 part [SWAP] 
├─sda6 8:6 0 3.8G 0 part 
├─sda7 8:7 0 3.8G 0 part 
├─sda8 8:8 0 3.8G 0 part 
└─sda9 8:9 0 167.5G 0 part / 

sdb 8:16 0 465.8G 0 disk 
└─sdb1 8:17 0 465.8G 0 part /hdd 

sdc 8:32 1 29.9G 0 disk 
└─sdc1 8:33 1 29.9G 0 part /media/jan/Jan_Stick_Ext4 

root@jan-desktop:~#
```

Comment: Please be more explicit in regards to "does not recognize". Does it show up in `lsblk`? How is the drive partitioned / formatted?

Comment: Yes it does show up.

Comment: root@jan-desktop:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 256.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  46.4G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0   3.8G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0   3.8G  0 part 
├─sda8   8:8    0   3.8G  0 part 
└─sda9   8:9    0 167.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /hdd
sdc      8:32   1  29.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  29.9G  0 part /media/jan/Jan_Stick_Ext4
root@jan-desktop:~#

Comment: root@jan-desktop:~# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 256.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  46.4G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0   3.8G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0   3.8G  0 part 
├─sda8   8:8    0   3.8G  0 part 
└─sda9   8:9    0 167.5G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /hdd
sdc      8:32   1  29.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1  29.9G  0 part /media/jan/Jan_Stick_Ext4
root@jan-desktop:~#

Comment: How can I attach a picture??

Comment: The drive is formatted as EXT4. and on the above list it is:  part / sdb 465.8G

Comment: sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /hdd

Comment: Please edit your question and include that information, with appropriate formatting so it's human-readable.  You can attach a picture using the picture icon in the edit window. Also, it sounds like the real problem is that your drive is not mounting, is that correct? Your system seems to recognize it just fine.

Comment: I am trying to attach pictures and lists but the systems scrambles it to one line. Sorry about that. But correct the system is not mounting the 500Gb HDD.

Comment: Does it show up in the file manager / Nautilus?  If so, does it mount if you click on it?

Comment: No,  the HDD doesn't show in Nautilus. Even not when I login as SuperUser and use Nautilus.

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `mount | grep "/dev/sd"`

Comment: "formatting" is a dangerous word when discussing entry level advice about handling hard disks... :)

Comment: I THINK the actual question is "why is the harddisk not automounted, and how can I make it get automounted and/or manually mount it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

**I still need the `terminal` output of...**

```
mount | grep "/dev/sd"
sudo blkid
sudo cat /etc/fstab
sudo fdisk -l
sudo lsblk

* screenshot of gparted /dev/sdb
```

To try and manually mount the drive...

In `terminal`...

- `sudo umount /hdd`
- `mkdir /media/jan/hdd`
- `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /media/jan/hdd`

Later... we edit /etc/fstab to make disk automount at boot...

- `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
- add `UUID={incomplete_answer} /media/jan/hdd ext4 defaults 0 2`
- save file and quit gedit
- `reboot`

Comment: I fiddled it already out yesterday and it comes down to the same but Thx anyway.